# mysql query with PHP if statment?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

The `$country` and `$job_type` values come from drop down list

```
if ($country == 'All' && $job_type == 'All') {
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv ")
}else {
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv WHERE country='$country' AND job='$job_type'")      
}
```

Comment: I'll just wait for you to finish the question :)

Comment: Without going to detail about all that's wrong in your code, your if statement logic seems inverted

Comment: Exacly, change the if to `if($country != 'All' || $job_type != 'All') { ... }`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: sry that's my first question her :-)

Comment: the problem not in ; i but it and not the logical about to run the first statement or the second one before the else,,,the error i get is : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)

Comment: @j0k thanks i will read it

Comment: @Fadi Abu Alnaser - What if country is 'All' and job_type isn't 'All'? What happens then?

Comment: will run the else statement i think ??!

Comment: @FadiAbuAlnaser since you specified `&&` it would go to the else (both need to equal 'All'), might I suggest you review the basics a bit to get a better understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing some `;`, try this:

```
if ($country == 'All' && $job_type == 'All') 
{
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv WHERE country='$country' AND job='$job_type'");
} else {
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv");
}
```

And Benjamin has a point, your IF logic doesn't seem right. Perhaps you want this?

```
if ($country == 'All' && $job_type == 'All') 
{
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv");
} else {
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cv WHERE country='$country' AND job='$job_type'");
}
```

Comment: thanks but i already try it that's what i get :
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)

Comment: @FadiAbuAlnaser Then that's somewhere else in your code, this particular code snippet is fine.

Comment: (unless the variables include a semi-colon injection)

Comment: man i found it very thanks i forget this word  "or die(mysql_error())" i add it in the second line and it's make the error